# windows phone 7 ctp - drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Have just installed Windows Phone 7 CTP (Visual Studio 2010 Express)

When I deploy the emulator loads but the deployment crashes with the following error.

Can anyone help please?

---

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone

Unable to start program '\Windows\taskhost.exe'.

The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk.

Comment: Getting the same issue, just opened the project on my work PC, greeted to the same message. Runs it fine at home.

Comment: Was getting the same issue on a project that worked fine on one machine, pulled it down from TFS on another machine and it dies the same way. Starting up a new XNA project on the failing machine and it warns me with the message in the posted blog entry below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was partly caused by also installing Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - it seems theres some slight compatibility issues between the CTP (Visual Studio 2010 Express) and Visual Studio Proper.

However I'm still struggling a bit on my home PC and have to use the following work around:

I deploy the app first (right click on the solution, deploy) - nothing appears in the emulator at this point.

Then when I run the app in Visual Studio in the usual manner it now appears in the emulator and I can debug etc.

I have to use this deploy then run process to see any changes.  If I just run then I don't get the latest changes - but at least the error discussed has stopped!

I've noticed that the emulator gets a lot more sluggish doing this, when I'm at work and just pressing the Run button things seems to run a great deal more smoothly.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Hi.. I am stuck with the same problem in Windows Phone 8. Any concrete solution for this???

Comment: I'm afraid not sorry, its probably over a year since I did any WP7 dev - but I don't think I was experiencing it towards the end, so maybe it got patched.  Sorry I can't be any more help.

Answer (score 0):

The application is failing to deploy.  This is most often associated with an unsupported video driver on the host PC.  Take a look at [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2010/03/16/9979644.aspx) to ensure you have proper video support.

Comment: its not the graphics error, I've had that on my laptop.  Also I found I can get it to run on the emulator by right clicking on the project clicking deploy and then going to menu on the emulator.  But it only works once for some reason, then I have to restart the emulator.